# Swipe between different images in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image: screenshot of an app]

As you can see in the image, the top half of the screen (below the search bar) contains images which can be swiped left and right. There are circles on the image denoting which image we are currently on. I want to achieve this in my android app. I'm pretty sure I have to use fragments for this. But I don't know how to do this particular thing. Someone please guide me or at least give me a link where this thing is explained.

Comment: You might have some luck looking for "Carousel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewPager` to achieve the slider

And for page indicator dots refer this [library project](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator)

This SO question can help you more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761794/2809326)

Comment: should I be using fragments ?? I'm just going to learn about ViewPager

Comment: added one more reference. check that too.